# R.java not generated while creating project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, fedora

I am already use eclipse mars in fedora 22. I have taken backup eclipse & SDK from fedora 22.Now I update my os to fedora 23. Now I am using the same eclipse and sdk in my updated fedora 23.Now I have face the below errors

**R.java** not generated Under gen folder
Please find screenshot for your easy reference
[project - hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Bsj.png)

Comment: switch to android studio

Comment: try to clean and build. You should use android studio for future development.

Comment: problem is that, your project is unable to build. Have you imported your project as Android project in eclipse?

Comment: Ok man, But why this happen may I know what was the reason. Clean project many times but error still remain

Comment: Cleaning doesn't only helps, you need to find out. There are n number reasons for this. 1. Missing the required styles 2. Errors in resources

Comment: VINIL I am not import existing project. This error happen while creating Android application project (HelloWorld).

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /home/bu/Bilal/eclipse/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt appcompat_v7  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Comment: eclipse throw above error

Comment: ... `manifest.java`?!

Comment: gen folder containing 3 .java files 1)BuildConfig.java 2)Manifest.java 3)R.java My gen folder only containing BuildConfig.java

Comment: I've **NEVER** seen a `Manifest.java` file since when I started Android programming, in 2010...

Comment: Sorry I am comparing with older workspace app. Me only create Manifest.java into the gen folder for some reason. Now I understood this also automatically generated into the gen folder. Again sorry for miss info. two only 1)BuildConfig.java 2)R.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. I got answer its work for me. R.java can't generate due to "Android SDK is initially intended for 32 bits. As I have 64bit Linux I need to install additional 32bit packages to make it work."

http://myprogrammingblog.com/2013/01/09/how-to-setup-adt-android-development-tools-on-64bit-fedora-17/

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development